# invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, utf-8

I have an HL7 file and the name in the file is caled "müller" and thats why i guess i get the Error:

Exiting

/usr/local/bundle/gems/simple_hl7-1.0.2/lib/simple_hl7/message.rb:115:in `split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/simple_hl7-1.0.2/lib/simple_hl7/message.rb:115:in `parse'
from /app/config/initializers/filewatcher.rb:9:in `block in '
from /app/config/initializers/filewatcher.rb:2:in `foreach'
from /app/config/initializers/filewatcher.rb:2:in `'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
...

this is my code

```
Dir.foreach('lib/hl7/') do |changes|

  if File.basename(changes, ".HL7").include?("ADT")
    p changes
    hl7_file = File.open("lib/hl7/#{changes.to_s}")
    hl7_read = File.read(hl7_file)
      
    hl7_msg = SimpleHL7::Message.parse(hl7_read)
    p hl7_msg
  end
end
```

i tried to hl7_read = File.read(hl7_file).encode('utf-8')
but that didnt work

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set the encoding for the file to UTF-8 or whatever the file originally was.

Have you read this article? https://thoughtbot.com/blog/fight-back-utf-8-invalid-byte-sequences

Btw you can open a file with specific encoding this way

`File.open("lib/hl7/#{changes.to_s}", :encoding => 'UTF-8')`

I think you have to find out what the original encoding is for that file. Maybe you should be sure that on you machine and server everything is UTF-8 per default and if something is not in UTF-8 you have to convert it first.